# How do I set this up?

Tags: python, database, django

I'm trying to set up my models so my data has this association:

[image: Database Diagram]

Here is what I'm thinking the code should look like:

```
# green model
class green(models.Model):

# grey model
class grey(models.Model):

# blue model
class blue(models.Model):
    green = models.ManyToManyField(green, blank=True, null=True)
    grey = models.ForeignKey(grey, blank=True, null=True)

# red model
class red(models.Model):
    red = models.ManyToManyField(blue, blank=True, null=True)
```

That is a red can have many blues, which can have many greens and a grey.

Am I setting this up right? Will I be able to follow a path to get to this data?

For example: find all the green objects and the grey object of blue1

Or do I need some ids in my models to associate them?

When I say ids, do I need all the blues to have a red id?

Comment: Obviously red, green and blue are stand in objects so knowing what they refer to would make this much easier. Failing that at least use some crows feet on the diagram.

Comment: I'm trying to make it abstract. Here is an example, a zoo has many exhibits, and each exhibit has many animals and a hot tub

Comment: I would go to that zoo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your diagram shows a strict relationship between everything, ie. a green belongs to only one blue and a gray thing belongs to only one blue.

If this is true, then your modeling won't work, you need [OneToOneFields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/examples/one_to_one/) to map the grays. Also, adding a `related_name` to your `ForeignKey`s allows you to have a "cleaner" name when querying. For example, `blue_object.greens` versus. `blue_object.green_set`

The following code allows a `red` object to have an explicit (non-shared) set of `blue` objects with their own set of `green` objects and a single `gray` object which they don't share.

```
# green model
class green(models.Model):
    blue = models.ForeignKey(blue, blank=True, null=True, related_name="greens") # I belong to one blue

# grey model
class grey(models.Model):
    gray = models.OneToOneField(grey, blank=True, null=True)
    # Put here for consistancy with pointing to a parent.

# blue model
class blue(models.Model):
    red = models.ForeignKey(red, blank=True, null=True, related_name="blues") )

# red model
class red(models.Model):
    pass
```

Comment: Are you reading it left to right? I'm reading it right to left. That is red has many blues, which has many greens and a grey. What am I not getting???

Comment: Yes. I am reading it correctly. A `ForeignKey` on the `blue` model means many `blue`s can link to the same `red` object.

Comment: Ah I get it! So if I do a search I have to search the Blue objects to find all the ones to associate with the red object in question? Or I have to search all the grey objects to find the one that associates with the blue object in question?

Comment: No. I'd suggest looking at how relationships are modelled in django. As I explain in the last line, even though they are modeled "backward" youc an still go `blue_object.greens.all()` to get all green objects for a given blue.

Comment: That is really cool Lego! Thanks for helping figure that out!

Comment: could I say: red_objects.blues.greens.all()?

Comment: No, you'd need to go `red_objects.blues.all()[0].greens.all()` For example, to get all of the greens of the first blues

Comment: red_objects.blues.all().greens.all() to get all the greens? and can I do red_objects.blues.get(blue_field=blue_field).greens.all() if blue had such field?

Comment: No. You can't do that first query. Do some research on the Django object model and ask a fresh question if you are still having troubles. The second should work.